# Intersection of two subspaces is the null vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be vector subspaces of the vector space $V$. Assume that each vector in one of them is orthogonal to all of the other. Show that the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: I know that any vector which is orthogonal to all other vectors of that subspace has to be the null vector of that subspace...can we use this result in the proof...i can not understand how to approach the problem

Comment: What if $W_1 \cap W_2 \neq \{ \boldsymbol{0} \}$?

Comment: Suppose $v\ne 0$ is in both subspaces, then it should be orthogonal to itself, which means $\langle v, v\rangle = 0$ but this would mean $v=0$.

Comment: Suppose that you can get your hands on some vector $\vec{v}$ that is in the intersection.  What would have to be true about $\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to prove that $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{\vec{0}\}$.  You can prove that if $\vec{v}$ is in the intersection, then $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

Suppose $\vec{v} \in W_1 \cap W_2$. Then $\vec{v}\in W_1$ and $\vec{v}\in W_2$. Because $\vec{v}\in W_2$, it is perpendicular to every vector in $W_1$. Because $\vec{v}\in W_1$, $\vec{v}$ is in particular perpendicular to *itself*:  $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v} = 0$.

By definition of the dot product, this implies that $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$.

---

This shows that *no other vector* can be in $W_1 \cap W_2$. The last detail is that $\vec{0}$ does belong to $W_1\cap W_2$ because $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces and so must each contain $\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be an inner product space (i.e. a vector space with an inner product) and suppose that $u,v \in V$.  We say that $u$ is *orthogonal* to $v$ if $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product.  Since this question is tagged with `linear-algebra`, it might be worth pointing out that the dot product is an inner product.  That is, $u$ is orthogonal to $v$ if $u\cdot v = 0$.

An inner product (i.e. the dot product) induces a *norm* on $V$.  By a norm, I mean a way of measuring the length of a vector.  The details are not really that important here.  The important bit is that if the norm of a vector is zero, then that vector must be the zero vector.  Specifically, if $v\in V$, then the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is defined by
$$\|v\|^2 := \langle v,v\rangle \qquad\text{(or $v\cdot v$)},$$
and
$$ v = 0 \iff \|v\| = \|v\|^2 = 0. $$
That is, if $v\cdot v = 0$, then $v$ must be the zero vector.

Now, suppose that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of some inner product space such that every element of $W_1$ is orthogonal to every element of $W_2$.  We want to understand the intersection of these to spaces, so suppose that $v \in W_1 \cap W_2$.  Since $v\in W_1$, if $w\in W_2$, then $v\cdot w = 0$.  But $v$ is also in $W_2$, which means that $v$ is one of the vectors that, when dotted with $v$, gives zero:
$$ v \cdot w = 0 \ \text{whenever $w\in W_2$, i.e. when $w=v$}
\implies v\cdot v = 0 \implies v = 0.$$
Therefore if $v\in W_1 \cap W_2$, then $v=0$.