# How to prove that a vector from the nullspace cannot be expressed as a linear combination of row vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let's say we have a matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$ with nullspace $N(A)$. Assume we have a non-trivial null space, i.e. $\exists q\neq 0\in N(A) $.

My question is the following:
consider $$Aq = 0$$ How can we show that q cannot be expressed using the rows of A?

We know that the nullspace and rowspace of A are orthogonal complements, which means they partition $R^n$. A vector v $\in R^n$ either belongs to null space **or** the rowspace of A.  How can we show that $q$ cannot be expressed as a combination of the rows of $A$?

This question is useful: [Intersection of two subspaces is the null vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383560/intersection-of-two-subspaces-is-the-null-vector)

Comment: I'm confused, because it seems like you've already arrived at the answer. The row space is the set of all vectors that can be formed by linear combinations of the rows, so the observation that $q \neq 0$ cannot be in both the row space and the null space is all you need.

Comment: I was thinking about this for a while, and I wasn't satisfied with "it follows from the definition".  I feel like there is one more step that I am missing, that will be illuminating to really understanding the concept.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what you yourself typed. If $q$ is orthogonal to vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$, then $q$ is orthogonal to any linear combination of those vectors. So can $q$ be itself a linear combination of those vectors?

Comment: It's not really a "by definition", it's more of a "by theorems ___ and ___", i.e. whatever results say that $N(A)$ is the perpendicular complement to the rowspace, and whatever result that says $W \cap W^\perp = \{0\}$ where $W$ is a subspace. There's some non-trivial results at play here! But, knowing these results does make the question quite straight forward.

Comment: @TedShifrin Interesting, is that going to lead to a proof by contradiction then? The main argument I see you making is 

$$c_1v_1 +...+ c_kv_k = x$$.

Then, multiply both sides by $q^T$, and we get 

$$q^Tx = 0$$. We finish by saying that x cannot be q, due to the inner product properties. But it seems like there is a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: Only the zero vector can be orthogonal to itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks both of you. So essentially, we are just doing something like $$A^Tc=q$$. And we wish to show that there exists no $c$ to create $q$; i.e. $q$ is not in $col(A^T)$. But somehow we don't need to say anything about invertibility of A, ambient dimension of A or anything else...

Comment: @user771918 I was thinking more about your line of thinking, and think that it is overall the more appropriate style of reasoning. But it seems there is a fine line between just relying on the definition and being too abstract. For instance,  $W\cap W^T = \{0\}$ is essentially the statement we want to prove, and then we would need to further go an prove that...

Comment: @information_interchange Do you have a proof that $W \cap W^\top = \{0\}$ already proven in your course? If so, then it's perfectly fine to rely on that. If not, I'd prove it as a lemma, then use the reasoning I gave above. If you were to write out the logic proving $W \cap W^\top = \{0\}$ again for this, you wouldn't be demonstrating anything new, just padding your proof. That said, when marking proofs, I much prefer to see padded proofs than anaemic proofs where I can't tell whether the person does or does not understand the material. But a short proof relying on known results is fine.